# teacher in English: teacher, instructor, professor, mentor, guru

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I have translated *teacher* into English. There is: *teacher, instructor, professor, mentor, guru.*

Hypothesis: *teacher* is a hypernym; *instructor* is for driving lessons, climbing, running; *professor* is a university one; *mentor* offers private classes only in certain fields; and *guru* is a term outside of schools for an expert in something.

I am studying the difference between them.

Which one of them is a high school teacher?
How about art school teacher?
How about instructor in car driving?
Is one of them a hypernym?

Note: I prefer the American English.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your hypothesis that *teacher* is a hypernym.  You could certainly say that *instructor, professor, mentor*, and *guru* are all more specific terms for teacher.

As for your specific questions:

If you are talking about someone teaching high school, you use *teacher*.

> I had a good math **teacher** and a bad science **teacher** in high school.

When it comes to art school teacher, I think *teacher* is acceptable.  It certainly doesn't sound weird.  I think it might also depend on the institution, but I imagine that *instructor* would work, too.  This is because *instructor* can be used as someone who is teaching at a higher level than high school (like at a university or, I would guess, an art school) but isn't necessarily a professor.

Your use of *instructor* for driving is very appropriate.  You could swap out *teacher* if you wanted and most people wouldn't even notice, but they are most often called "driving instructors".

Comment: I would say that an instructor was someone who taught a very practical skill such as driving or scuba diving. 'Mentor' is a more metaphorical term for someone an individual sees as a wise advisor to them personally. A guru is a Hindu religious teacher.

Comment: I know guru in the field of seduction - Mystery. So I do not thing that guru is only for Hindu.